# How to secure communication between page and browser extension?

Tags: javascript, browser-extensions

In [my browser plugin](https://github.com/Sjord/messpostage/blob/master/messpostage/content.js) I want to detect any use of a built-in JavaScript function. I override this function by injecting a piece of code onto the page. This code then triggers an event, and an event handler sends a message to my extension using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`.

The problem is that now any page on the internet can also trigger the event and communicate with my extension. I want just my injected script to be able to communicate with my extension, to avoid a security problem such as with [Grammarly](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/project-zero/issues/detail?id=1527&desc=3).

How can I secure the communication between the injected script and the extension. I want to override a native JavaScript function, so I have to put script on the page (as opposed to the content script). Because it's on the page, I can't call chrome.runtime.sendMessage directly.

Edit: I thought of [this solution](https://github.com/Sjord/messpostage/pull/4/files): create a random secret key in the content script, and only handle events with that secret key. It feels like a total hack, so the question is still if there is a "right" way to do this.

Comment: i would change all copies of the string "messageListenerDetected" to securityToken from your 2nd example. That way, it's a different event name each time. maybe something alpha instead, like `[].map.call(crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint16Array(10)), x=>x.toString(36)).join("")`. does that onload event fire? you might call `document.currentScript.remove()` inside of overrideFunctions() so that other scripts can't possibly rip the token from the DOM (as it would all be sync execution and gone before they could), or if there's a way to call eval() on the site page, that would be even better.